# Disable Crashlytics debug logging

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I need to disable crash logging while debug environment is running. I followed this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation). And I see that I can archive this behaviour using `-FIRDebugEnabled` as you can see in attached screen shot.
[image]

So where can I use `-FIRDebugEnabled` in Xcode?
I try to add it here, but it didn't help - I still logging crash reports.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use right configuration schema. Now it work's correct.
[image]